# I use cURL google search Scrape in php

Tags: php

```
$q = str_replace(" ", "+", $query);

    $useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0";
    $ch = curl_init ("");
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&tbo=d&site=&source=hp&q=".$q);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent); // set user agent
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    echo $output = curl_exec ($ch);die;
    curl_close($ch);
```

i can't get result from google html. result javascript. thanks

Answer (score 0):

google has some strict check,here's my query link,it works ok on [http://aiddroid.com](http://aiddroid.com/api/g.php)

```
$url = "https://www.google.dk/search?&q=".urlencode($query)."&hl=zh-CN&tbs={$tbs}&prmd={$prmd}&ei={$ei}&start=$start&sa=N";
```

[image]